# SSIS Process records between header and trailer in flat file

Tags: ssis, batch-processing, flat-file, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package that uses a conditional split to get any batch header or trailer in a line delimited flat file, take the first line, and grab an error code from it. If the error code is > 0, I write out all of the normal records in between the batch header and trailer to a report with that error code. Otherwise I write out only normal records with errors codes. Here's what that example looks like:

```
//No batch level error
00000BH
00123NRNormalRecordData
00000NRNormalRecordDataNoError
00000BT
```

Which would look like:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════╗
║   Error   ║   Record Data    ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║       123 ║ NormalRecordData ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

And:

```
//Batch level error
05555BH
00000NRNormalRecordData
00000NRNormalRecordData
00000BT
```

Which would look like:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Error ║       Record Data       ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════════╣
║  5555 ║ NormalRecordData        ║
║       ║                         ║
║  5555 ║ NormalRecordData        ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

**My problem is** with multiple batches this now screws up (There use to only ever be one batch). now I want to do something like the following

```
//Multi batch
00000BH
00123NRNormalRecordError
00000NRNormalRecord
00000BT
00000BH
00000SRSecondaryRecordType //want to ignore batches with no NR normal records
00000BT
05555BH
00000NRNormalRecord
00000NRNormalRecord
00000BT
```

Due to saving the batch level error into a variable and checking if it's null when I write the records out this report would incorrectly look like:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════════╗
║ Error ║    Record Data      ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╣
║  5555 ║ NormalRecordError   ║
║  5555 ║ SecondaryRecordType ║
║  5555 ║ NormalRecord        ║
║  5555 ║ NormalRecord        ║
║  5555 ║ NormalRecord        ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════════╝
```

When I would want it to look like:

```
╔═══════╦═══════════════════╗
║ Error ║    Record Data    ║
╠═══════╬═══════════════════╣
║  123  ║ NormalRecordError ║
║  5555 ║ NormalRecord      ║
║  5555 ║ NormalRecord      ║
╚═══════╩═══════════════════╝
```

This is because the logic looks a little something like:

- store batch level error get all normal records with an error, unless
- batch level error > 0 then get them all write all rows with batch
- level error if there was one or write only normal rows that error
  (this case would work as intended, because the batch level variable
  is not populated)

**My first thought** was a conditional split. However, this would only let me do a condition at the row level, where as I need context of rows that have come prior.

How would you tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a script component transformation to parse the column and add rows based on your conditions.  The header error can be stored in a variable that is declared outside the Input0_ProcessInputRow method.  Here are the steps that I used:

1. I used your data above to make a single column flatfile with the column name data
2. Add a script component as transformation
3. Check Data as a input column
4. Add new Output called RecordOutput
5. Add columns to out put: error as int, RecordData as string

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    int error;

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        //gets the row type

        string rowType = Row.Data.Substring(5, 2);

        //only sets the error variable if it is a header record
        if (rowType == "BH")
        {
            error = Convert.ToInt32(Row.Data.Substring(0, 5));
        }

        //Only adds a record for NR rows
        if (rowType == "NR" && (error > 0 || Convert.ToInt32(Row.Data.Substring(0, 5)) > 0))
        {
            RecordOutputBuffer.AddRow();
            if (error > 0)
            {
                RecordOutputBuffer.Error = error;
            }
            else
            {
                RecordOutputBuffer.Error = Convert.ToInt32(Row.Data.Substring(0, 5));
            }
            RecordOutputBuffer.RecordData = Row.Data.Substring(7, Row.Data.Length - 7);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is what the component looks like:
[image]

Here are the results:
[image]